# Firebase Live score push notifications using fcm

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an app, a live scores app that allow the users to subscribe to their favorite teams, using FCM topics subscriptions, I need help to delivery the notifications to that users.

Right now I can send regular notifications to the devices, I can send notifications manually via console, admin node.js, rest api, even for the subscription topics that users subscribe, I can also list the subscriptions of a specific registration id.

So... My topics that users subscribe are team ids (football teams), what I want to do is notify the users that subscribe to a specific topic when some game events happens like, goals, game status (game starts, half-time, 2nd half starts, games finish) it's a very common use case for a push notifications system.

I store my games data in firebase database, I get it from an external provider and is updated in "real-time" and look like:

```
{
        "AwayTeamShort": "ANZ",
        "League": "Russian Premier League",
        "comp_id": "1457",
        "events": [
            {
                "assist": "G. Gabulov",
                "assist_id": "29779",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177131",
                "minute": "46",
                "player": "M. Kazankov",
                "player_id": "113277",
                "result": "",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "",
                "assist_id": "",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177132",
                "minute": "57",
                "player": "I. Yediev",
                "player_id": "",
                "result": "",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "yellowcard"
            },
            {
                "assist": "K. Bazelyuk",
                "assist_id": "269373",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177133",
                "minute": "57",
                "player": "A. Katsaev",
                "player_id": "92363",
                "result": "",
                "team": "visitorteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "J. Lipartia",
                "assist_id": "41506",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177134",
                "minute": "58",
                "player": "K. Mamtov",
                "player_id": "29851",
                "result": "",
                "team": "visitorteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "E. Balyajkin",
                "assist_id": "6770",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177135",
                "minute": "67",
                "player": "N. Kalinski",
                "player_id": "",
                "result": "",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "R. Koryan",
                "assist_id": "123728",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177136",
                "minute": "68",
                "player": "M. Markovic",
                "player_id": "139251",
                "result": "[1-0]",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "goal"
            },
            {
                "assist": "P. Yakovlev",
                "assist_id": "82061",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177137",
                "minute": "71",
                "player": "P. Dolgov",
                "player_id": "309265",
                "result": "",
                "team": "visitorteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "R. Koryan",
                "assist_id": "123728",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177138",
                "minute": "72",
                "player": "V. Nikiforov",
                "player_id": "26213",
                "result": "",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "subst"
            },
            {
                "assist": "",
                "assist_id": "",
                "extra_min": "",
                "id": "23177139",
                "minute": "89",
                "player": "A. Dovbnya",
                "player_id": "123582",
                "result": "",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "yellowcard"
            },
            {
                "assist": "",
                "assist_id": "",
                "extra_min": "2",
                "id": "231771310",
                "minute": "90",
                "player": "T. Phibel",
                "player_id": "58795",
                "result": "",
                "team": "visitorteam",
                "type": "yellowcard"
            },
            {
                "assist": "",
                "assist_id": "",
                "extra_min": "2",
                "id": "231771311",
                "minute": "90",
                "player": "S. Bryzgalov",
                "player_id": "122214",
                "result": "",
                "team": "visitorteam",
                "type": "yellowcard"
            },
            {
                "assist": "V. Nikiforov",
                "assist_id": "26213",
                "extra_min": "5",
                "id": "231771312",
                "minute": "90",
                "player": "N. Kalinski",
                "player_id": "",
                "result": "[2-0]",
                "team": "localteam",
                "type": "goal"
            }
        ],
        "formatted_date": "08.08.2017",
        "ft_score": "[2-0]",
        "ht_score": "[0-0]",
        "id": "2211727",
        "localteam_id": "14810", 
        "localteam_name": "SKA Khabarovsk",
        "localteam_score": "2",
        "region": "Russia",
        "season": "2017/2018",
        "status": "FT",
        "time": "08:00”,
        "venue": "Stadion imeni V.I. Lenina (Khabarovsk)",
        "venue_city": "Khabarovsk",
        "venue_id": "88600",
        "visitorteam_id": "14786",
        "visitorteam_name": "FK Anzi Makhackala",
        "visitorteam_score": "0",
        "week": "5"
    }
```

The users subscribe to the team id in the json above the team ids are visitorteam_id, localteam_id, these ids are always the same for that team doesn't matter if is visitor or local.

My Subscriptions on Instance ID APIs looks like(I then store it in the db but doesn't matter for this question) :

```
{
  "application":"com.iid.example",
  "authorizedEntity":"123456782354",
  "platform":"Android",
  "attestStatus":"ROOTED",
  "appSigner":"1a2bc3d4e5",
  "connectionType":"WIFI",
  "connectDate":"2017-08-07
  "rel":{
    "topics":{
      "42332":{"addDate":"2017-08-07"},
      "14810":{"addDate":"2017-08-07"},
      "14786":{"addDate":"2017-08-07"}

    }
  }
}
```

So... How can I notify the devices that subscribe to a particular topic (team id) about goals in games the team they subscribe are playing ?

Ps: I know that probably the solution is complex, but every help, examples will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Firebase Cloud function.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

You can create a Firebase Cloud function that "subscribe" to changes and then automatically fires the push notification.

Comment: hi Javi, like i mention i can subscribe to topics and get notif for changes in the DB my question is more about the approach to work with my json and "connect " that to a specific topic, for example :